# To validate the entered CVV code with saved credit card using stripe

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe with `JAVA SDK` and I'm trying to check the user entered **CVV** code. I've the `stripe customer_id` and the `stripe card_id`. I want to verify the **CVV** code before charging the user.

So is there any way in stripe to validate my Card with CVV.

Comment: And what is your question? Sorry, but this is not a service were you drop ideas/requirements and other people tell you how to implement that.